# Jquery, Add elements every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a growth map similar to http://projects.flowingdata.com/walmart/.

I am using https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-gMap to do the maping

What i've got so far is a button that when I click it I want to start the animation.  The onclick code is:

```
<script>
    $("input.buttonB").click(function(){  
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gMap('addMarker', {
                latitude:   41.60252,
                longitude: -100.32855,
                content: 'Some HTML content'
                }
            );
        }, 2000);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gMap('addMarker', {
                latitude:   11.60252,
                longitude: -110.32855,
                content: 'Some HTML content'
                }
            );
        }, 2000);        
    });
</script>
```

Problem is, the markers don't appear on screen every 2 seconds.  The window waits 4 seconds then displays both of them at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your example wouldn't you want the second timeOut to be 4000 ms?

Comment: Why do you have two timeouts?

Comment: Ultimately there will be some hundreds of elements with groups displayed every 2 seconds.  There are two timeouts because I misunderstood timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should have something like this (untested):

```
var markerData = [{
    lat: "something",
    lng: "something",
    html: "something"},
{
    lat: "something",
    lng: "something",
    html: "something"
}];

function showNextMarker() {
    var current = markerData.shift();
    $('#map_canvas').gMap('addMarker', {
        latitude: current.lat,
        longitude: current.lng,
        content: current.html
    });
}

$("input.buttonB").click(function(){  
    var i = window.setInterval(function() {
        showNextMarker();
        if (markerData.length == 0) {
            i = window.clearInterval(i);
        };
    }, 2000);    
});
```

Comment: great! I see the value of shift();, didn't know it before in jQuery.

Comment: @Michael Mao - It's plain-old-JavaScript, and the catch it that it actually removes the first element from the array, but it can be useful in that when you *don't* need to re-use an array since solutions making use of `shift` tend to be shorter.

Comment: I like this solution.  I tested it and it works.  One problem though -- the loop never ends.

Comment: Awesome.  I updated the answer to reflect what I've tested and have working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't "stop" and wait for a timeout. So if you set two 2-second timeouts right after each other, they'll both execute 2 seconds later.

Why your code should execute *4* seconds later, I can't say. Nothing indicates it would. But timeouts can be delayed if the computer is busy. A timeout only means that something will happen *as soon as possible* after the time limit has run out.

In any case, I'd suggest something like:

```
(function(){
    var markers = [
        {
            latitude:   41.60252,
            longitude: -100.32855,
            content: 'Some HTML content'
        },
        {
            latitude:   11.60252,
            longitude: -110.32855,
            content: 'Some HTML content'
        }
        // add more here
    ];

    function addMarker() {
        $('#map_canvas').gMap('addMarker', markers.shift());

        if( markers.length > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(addMarker, 2000);
        }
    }

    $("input.buttonB").click(function(){
        addMarker();
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML

```
<button>click</button>
<div class="output"></div>
```

The JS

```
$(function(){
    var coords = [
        {x:100, y:200},
        {x:5, y:10},
        {x:300, y:400}
    ];

    var i = 0;

    var displayCoord = function(){
       $("div").append('<p> x:' + coords[i].x + ' y:' + coords[i].y + '</p>');
        if(i < coords.length){
            i += 1;
            setTimeout(displayCoord, 2000);
        }
    };

    $("button").click(displayCoord);
});
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFMYe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would have both events happen after 2s (not 4s - are you using a debugger like FireBug that would make it seem slower?). I think you want the first anonymous function to set up the second's timer.